# EF4.1 How to map List of properties from different tables

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, metadata, dynamic-data

Assume we have the following class:

```
public class MyEntity
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public int EntityType { get; set; }
   public List<integer> DataValues { get; set; }
}
```

The table structure is like this:

```
MyEntity
Id uniqueidentifier
```

I want to store the values for DataValues in different tables depending upon the EntityType. So for example, MyEntity1 will have two integer fields, and MyEntity2 might have three integer fields.

```
MyEntity1
EntityId (FK to MyEntity)
Integer1 int
Integer2 int

MyEntity2
EntityId (FK to MyEntity)
Integer1 int
Integer2 int
Integer3 int
```

So if I have an instance of type "MyEntity1", my tables will have following values:

```
MyEntity
Id          EntityType
---------------------
someguid1     1

MyEntity1
EntityId  Integer1   Integer2
------------------------------
someguid1 100         200
```

At runtime another class say MyEntityDefinition stores how many integers does the entity store, by referring to this class I can know that if entity is of type of MyEntity1 then it contains two integer values.

I would want map this table structure to MyEntity class, any possible ways of doing this?

PS: I do not want to define classes MyEntity1, MyEntity2. I just want to use the table structure (MyEntity, MyEntity1, MyEntity2) to store data.

Basically I was evaluating EF 4.1 ins scenarios where entity definitions are not fixed and can be updated by users. The information (metadata) about the entities is stored in other tables

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible, but how about something like this:

```
public class MyEntity
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public int EntityType { get; set; }

   public static List<int> DataValues(MyEntity obj)
   {
      if (obj.EntityType == 1)
      {
         MyEntity1 e1 = (MyEntity1)obj;
         // TODO: return list of integers from e1
      }
   }
}


public class MyEntity1 : MyEntity
{
  public int Integer1 {get;set;}
  public int Integer2 {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Would be better if polymorphism is used

Comment: Interesting idea, but I do not want to define classes MyEntity1, MyEntity2. I just want to store my data in that table structure